# error for 'No ID Found'

Tags: python-2.7

I keep getting an error, saying that there is no id for the game, here's the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 4, in <module>
Error: Attempted to look up malformed environment ID: flashgames.CoasterRacer-V0.  (Currently all IDs must be of the form ^(?:[\w:-]+\/)?([\w:.-]+)-v(\d+)$.)`

here's the code:

```
import gym
import universe

env = gym.make('flashgames.CoasterRacer-V0')
observation_n = env.reset()

while True:
  observation_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n]
  observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
 env.render()
```

I have the code on a repl.it thing, here is the link:
https://repl.it/@32_bits_in_a_by/game-emulator